# Dual booting windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04. NO internet on ubuntu

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

Just made a dual boot with Ubuntu and Win 10. Windows 10 have an internet connection while Ubuntu doesn't.

Tested a few things and it seems like Ubuntu is not using my NIC or somehting? im new to ubuntu and i've tried most of the fixes that i found. Nothing worked.

Some more info.

```
ip a

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

user@user:~$ sudo lshw -C Network
[sudo] password for user: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df200000-df21ffff
```

It's a desktop system and it only has ethernet.

Both windows 10 and Ubuntu are fresh install.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/786605/ubuntu-14-04-ethernet-and-wifi-not-working-unclaimed-network see that info may help you to your solution. Also see in the site, you may found similar situationsbas yours.

Comment: Please follow the instructions listed at the following question so that we can help you. Thanks! https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Please post the text file here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and then post the link in your question. Thanks!